# What's the usage of knowing $p(\ln\sigma) = \text{const}$ in noninformative prior

Tags: probability-distributions

In the PRML equation 2.239, for a non-informative prior of a scale parameter, the probability mass for interval $A \leq\sigma \leq B$ and $A/c\leq \sigma \leq B/c$ for any choice of all A and B should be the same. Hence $p(\sigma) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma} $.

In the following, it said it is convenient to consider prior distribution in its log form and have $p(\ln\sigma)=\text{const}$

But what's the usage of $p(\ln\sigma)=\text{const}$ ?

Comment: Is the very next sentence unclear to you?  [PRML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) p. 119 (139 of 758): "Thus, for this prior there is the same probability mass in the range $1 \leq \sigma \leq 10$ as in the range $10 \leq \sigma \leq 100$ and in $100 \leq \sigma \leq 1000$."

Comment: @EricTowers Hi, I just found hard to understand the conclusion $p(ln\sigma) = const$. Why think in for of  $ln\sigma$ will be convenient and what could we do about the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The cited passage goes on to explicitly mention that the same probability mass falls in each decade: $[1,10]$, $[10,100]$, $[100,1000]$, ...  Equivalently, the same probability mass falls in each octave: $[1,2]$, $[2,4]$, $[4,8]$, ...  Equivalently, the same probability mass falls in each partition by integer powers of a positive constant different from $1$.

In the text between (2.236) and (2.237), we have the text

> The parameter $\sigma$ is known as a scale parameter, and the density exhibits [scale invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance).

Scale invariance (in dimension $1$) is a synonym for the previous sentences about power partitions.

Further, at the top of p. 118, we have

> If we have a distribution $p(x\mid \lambda)$ governed by a parameter $\lambda$, we might be tempted to propose a prior distribution $p(\lambda) = \mathrm{const}$ as a suitable prior.

The text then explains that might be fine for a discrete parameter, but is (generally) incorrect for a continuous parameter.  Ending with

> If, however, we are to choose a prior distribution that is constant, we must take care to use an appropriate representation for the parameters.

Taking these together in the context of (2.239), we should be looking for a (re-)parametrization leading to a constant probability density.  Since $\sigma > 0$ by assumption, one may parametrize by $ \lambda = \sigma$, $\lambda = \sigma +1$, $\lambda = \sigma^3$, $\lambda = \mathrm{e}^\sigma$, $\lambda = \sqrt{\sigma}$, or any of several other functions of $\sigma$.  There is one simple choice for which the probability density is constant for the new choice of parameter : $\lambda = \ln \sigma$.  (There are "silly" variations, like $\log_7 \sigma$ or $\ln(2\sigma)$, but these are just obscurations of the plain logarithmic relation.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you elaborate how you make the choice of parameter to be $\lambda = \ln \sigma$?

Comment: @Kelvin_neverKnow : ALready answered in the last paragraph.  It is (one of) the choice(s) of (re-)parametrization that produces a constant probability density.  How does one know that?  By having absorbed the information in this section about scale invariance and parametrization choices that are convenient for expressing that property.